# Simple ODE question(solution verification). A student learns 150 Chinese characters each month and forgets 10% of what they have learned

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, differential, initial-value-problems

> A student learns 150 Chinese characters each month and forgets 10% of what they have learned each month as well.
>
> 1. Construct a differential equation suitable from the problem
> 2. what can we learn about the slope field of this equation?
> 3. Find a solution with a suitable initial value, did what we learn about the slope in part 2 match what we got here?
> 4. If the student must know 1200 characters to pass the basic exam and 2000 for the advanced how long will it take the student to learn each of the exams?

---

EDIT - these are my final solutions:

for the first part:
let $C(t)$ be the number of characters the student learns , while $t$ is the time in months and $C(0)=0$ as the initial value assuming the student did not know any letters before and $r=0.1$ the number of characters the student forgets.

the recursive function would be $C(t+1)=C(t)-0.1 \cdot C(t)+C(0)$

not to find the continuous function in time $\triangle t$:

$C(t+\triangle t)=C(t)-0.1 \cdot C(t) \cdot \triangle t + 150 \cdot \triangle t$

from here we can get to a derivative by definition form

$\lim_ \limits{\triangle t \to 0} \frac{C(t+\triangle t)-C(t)}{\triangle t}=-0.1 \cdot C(t)+150$

finally we get $C'(t)=150-0.1 \cdot C(t)$

part two:
I am not sure if this is right or what I can actually learn from that, but if $(C(t)=1500$ then $(C'(t)=0$ which i guess means that at at the rate of studyig the maximum number of characters the student will be able to learn is $1500$
[image: the slope field]

part three:

solving using separation of variables method and the initial value $C(0)=0$
we get
$C'(t)=150-0.1C(t)$ with out initial value $C(0)=0$

$\frac{dc}{dt}=150-0.1C(t)$ $\to$

$\frac{dc}{150-0.1C(t)}=dt$ $\to$

$\int\frac{1}{150-0.1 \cdot C(t)}dc=\int dt$ $\to$

$\ln(150-0.1 \cdot C(t))=t+D$

lastly $C(t)=\frac{150-T \cdot e^{0.1t}}{0.1}$ $=$ $C(t)=1500+T \cdot e^{-0.1 \cdot t}$

we plug in $C(0)=0$ and get $T=-1500$

$C(t)=1500-1500e^{-0.1t}$

part four:

for the basic exam:$C(t)=1500-1500e^{-0.1t}=1200$

then I normally solved this and got $t=10ln(5)$

for the advanced exam: $C(t)=1500-1500e^{-0.1t}=2000$

then I got $e^{-0.1t}=-\frac{1}{3}$ but it is not possible to have negative time and $t \not \in \Bbb R$

> ---

This is what I tried first but it is wrong (irrelevant)

I started solving but then I put my equation in a slope field graph and it looked weird so I was unsure of my way.

let $C(t)$ be the number of characters while $t$ is the time in months
according to given information $C(0)=150$
the student learns $150$ characters each months and also forgets$ 10%$ of what they know so

$C(t+1)=C(t)-0.1 \cdot C(t)+C(0)$ This is my first question , should it be the one I provided or $C(t+1)=C(t)-0.1 \cdot C(t)+C(0) \cdot t$?

now to check the continuous form assume we want time $\triangle t$

so $C(t+\triangle t)=C(t)-0.1 \cdot C(t) \cdot \triangle t + C(0) \cdot \triangle t$

from here we can get to a derivative by definition form

$\lim_ \limits{\triangle t \to 0} \frac{C(t+\triangle t)-C(t)}{\triangle t}=-0.1 \cdot C(t)+C(0)$

finally we get $C'(t)=150-0.1 \cdot C(t)$

when I tried getting the slope field it showed everything points upwards so I think I am wrong

maybe it should be $C'(t)=150 \cdot t-0.1 \cdot C(t)$

EDIT - the second part of the question:

now we solve $C'(t)=150-0.1C(t)$ with out initial value $C(0)=150$
$\frac{dc}{dt}=150-0.1C(t)$ $\to$ $\frac{dc}{150-0.1C(t)}=dt$ $\to$ $\int\frac{1}{150-0.1 \cdot C(t)}dc=\int dt$ $\to$ $\ln(150-0.1 \cdot C(t))=t+D$ lastly $C(t)=\frac{150-T \cdot e^{0.1t}}{0.1}$ $=$ $C(t)=1500-T \cdot e^{-0.1 \cdot t}$

we plug in $C(0)=150$ and get $T=1350$

so the solution would be $C(t)=1500-1350 \cdot e^{-0.1t}$

is this correct for the second part?

Why is it in the answers $C(t)=1500-1500 \cdot e^{-0.1t}? $isn't the initial condition $C(0)=150$?

if $C(0)=0$ and not $C(0)=150$ it means the first part of my question is wrong because the continuous form will be different

Thanks for any help and tips , I will update my process with each help

Hopefully the translations are understandable

Comment: $C'(t)=150-0.1 \cdot C(t)$ is the right differential equation.

Comment: @callculus42 But why does it seem like 150 is a constant here? the student learns 150 every month and forgets 10% of what he learned.. wouldn't this mean that a point here C(t) will be greater than 150?

Comment: 150 is a constant for the differential. But for the function itself the constant is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

part two :

From $C'(t)=150-0.1 \cdot C(t)$, we have
$$C'(t)=0\iff C(t)=1500$$
$$C'(t)\gt 0\iff C(t)\lt 1500$$

$C(t)$ is strictly increasing only when $C(t)\lt 1500$, so we can at least say that $C(t)\leqslant 1500$ holds.

(This does not necessarily mean that the maximum number of characters the student will be able to learn is $1500$. See below.)

---

part three :

You got $C(t)=1500-1500e^{-0.1t}$.

> did what we learn about the slope in part 2 match what we got here?

Yes. Since $e^{-0.1t}$ is positive, we have $C(t)\lt 1500$.

(There is no $t$ such that $C(t)=1500$. We have $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty}C(t)=1500$.)

---

**Added** :

Part 1 looks correct except the following two parts :

- It is not correct that "$r=0.1$ the number of characters the student forgets". It is the rate at which the student forgets.
- I don't think that $C(t+1)=C(t)-0.1 \cdot C(t)+C(0)$ holds. For example, substituting $t=0$, we get $C(1)=0$ which is not correct. I think you can start with $C(t+\triangle t)=C(t)+\bigg(150-0.1  C(t)\bigg)\triangle t$ where $\bigg(150-0.1  C(t)\bigg)\triangle t$ represents the number of characters the students learns from time $t$ to time $t+\triangle t$.

Part 4 looks correct.

Comment: Thank you , and I'm guessing since you did not mention them part 1 and part 4 are correct?

Comment: @Adamrk : I added some explanations.

Comment: so if I just add $150$ is a constant , and set $c(0)=0$ that would solve it ?

Comment: @Adamrk : I would say yes.

Answer (score 2):

I agree wih callculus42  that the right differential equation is $$C^{\prime}+\frac{C}{10}=150.$$ Then the general solution is $$C=Ke^{-\frac{t}{10}}+1500$$ With the initial condition " When $t=0, C=0$", we cee that $K=-1500$, so the general formula is $$C=-1500e^{-\frac{t}{10}}+1500.$$

Comment: Thank you , but isn't it supposed to be $-1350$?